# Переустановка Windows

Tags: windows

Сейчас я использую в качестве основного OS Windows 10, ранее использовал Windows 7 и сейчас я хочу откатиться обратно на предыдущую версию ОС. У меня такой вопрос, этого сделать можно?

Comment: откатиться (как в вопросе) или переустановить (как в заголовке)?

Comment: Откатиться на предыдущую версию ОС не рекомендуется ( если еще и получиться ) А вот переустановить  вы можете на любую ОСь какая вам вздумается

Comment: Ну например, переустановить c Windows 10 на 7)) До этого момента очень долгое время использовал только 7-ки

Answer (score 2):

1. Делаете бекап всех важных данных, желательно на **внешний** носитель, а не просто другой том диска, чисто на всякий случай
2. Выключаете комп, подключаете флешку/диск с установщиком
3. Устанавливаете винду. Выбираете там ТОМ, который был с десяткой, форматируете, устанавливаете

Установщики десятки и семерки вроде похожи, проблем быть не должно...